# Does earth revolution speed slowing down because of small drag from space is not empty?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, drag, earth, tidal-effect

I read that universe is not empty, in least dense parts has 1000 atoms  per cubic meter, does that slow down earth speed?

Why these atoms are there, why they are not attracted by surrounding gravity fields?

Comment: Space is far too empty for any effect to be significant. Besides, we know the big effect is caused by gravitational interaction with, for example, the moon, where energy is dissipated by the interactions.

Comment: Hi user628075. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope estimate of the drag vs. tidal effects?

Comment: @matt_black But this atoms limit speed of rockets

Comment: @Qmechanic no I dont

Comment: @user628075 atoms *in the atmosphere* limit the speed of rockets *in the atmosphere*. They have no notable effect on the speed in empty space.